# routing to blank request in mvc asp.net using IIS 6.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis-6, routes

I'm attempting to connect to my published website using the following url.
http://www.mywebsite.com/
I keep getting:
The incoming request does not match any route.
Here are my routing rules:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default2",                                              // Route name
                "/",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

I'm using authentication as such:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
            <forms loginUrl="~/Home.aspx/Index"
                    protection="All"
                    timeout="300"/>
        </authentication>
```

When I'm not authenticated it goes to the correct page, but when I am authenticated it throws the above error.  I'm using IIS 6.0 and doing the whole rewriting url workaround option.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `"/"` in "Default2" route to `""`:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default2", "", new { ... });
```

Also make sure you have followed this guide: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx for `Default.aspx` file if you are on IIS6.