# blank pages/routing issue with asp.net mvc 2 iis7 integrated windows7 vs2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing, integrated

I've been searching though a number of posts and still can't seem to get a straight answer or at least one that works for me. From what I can tell is is some kind of routing issue. In fact I'm pretty certain of it. When I visit any of my web pages it comes back as a blank page with no data.

Also I am using VS2010 asp.net mvc2 on window7 using iis7 integrated. The purpose of using iis7 integrated is because when I publish the site to my godaddy hosting provider I want to be able to replicate the security permissions locally so after publishing the site should not have any surprise issues that pop up.

I tried using the Default.aspx trick described here [ASP.net MVC on IIS 7 returning blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413035/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-returning-blank-page) but the same problem only the root page gets displayed and no other routes are available.

I have also tried crating a empty route described here 
[routing to blank request in mvc asp.net using IIS 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659465/routing-to-blank-request-in-mvc-asp-net-using-iis-6-0) 
and here 
[I am getting a blank page while deploying MVC application on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557730/i-am-getting-blank-page-while-deploying-mvc-application-on-iis)

I am also using the Route debugger found here 
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Using the Route debugger when I visit http://localhost/ I still get a blank page with no data. But When I visit http://localhost/Home.aspx the route debugger then kicks in and displays the fallowing

http://j.imagehost.org/0476/routes.png

When I add

routes.MapRoute("Default2", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

above or below the catchall route

routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }); // Parameter defaults

it does the same thing blank page when I visit http://localhost/ I still get a blank page with no data. And when I visit http://localhost/Home.aspx the route debugger kicks in and displays the fallowing

http://a.imagehost.org/0115/routes2.png

Is there anything else that I can try to get my pages to display properly? Seems like a lot of people are having the same issue but with iis6 classic or older mvc versions have have seen very few posts about people having blank page issue with my configuration of VS2010 asp.net mvc2 on window7 using iis7 integrated.

Any help is greatly apreciated!

Comment: Did you had any luck? Encountering the same problem now ...

Comment: Well, found my answer with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852251/getting-an-asp-mvc2-vs2010-application-to-work-in-iis-7-5

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer as an answer? :-) If it is one...

Answer (score 4):

"HTTP Errors" and "HTTP Redirection" services must be added to "Web Server (IIS) role. If you wan't to get static content like CSS and Javascript working, too, enable "Static Content" service as well.

Comment: That certainly allowed me to see an actual error rather than a blank page! Thanks

Comment: Thx, had the blank page error after installing iis7, didnt even show the default iis welcome page. Enabling these options solved it.